# ASP code not reading SQL field correctly

Tags: sql, asp-classic, if-statement

I'm pulling a field from a table and doing different things depending on what the result is. Here's my code

```
<%stringA ="Select field From table Where something=1"
set response = connFW.Execute(stringA )
set result = response ("field")
If result ="y" Then 
Response.Write("The field is: " & result )
End If%>
```

It outputs this:

```
The field is: y
```

Then, later, I have an If statement:

```
<% ElseIf result ="y"  or Session("customer_id") <> "" Then
Do Something
%>
```

But it never executes what's in the ElseIf statement! It says right at the top of the page that it gave the correct result! Am I missing something?

Note: To avoid confusion, this code is at the top of the page:

```
Set connFW = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connFW.ConnectionTimeout = Application("FW_ConnectionTimeout")
connFW.CommandTimeout = Application("FW_CommandTimeout")
connFW.Open Application("FW_ConnectionString")
```

Comment: If you have ElseIf with condition result="y" which is satisfied in first If how will the control come to this line.    So better have just Session("consumer_id") <> "" in ElseIf or put it inside If block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your complete code, it's hard to see where the exact problem is, but I see two possibilities. Either you have an "ElseIf" on its own, in which case you should change ElseIf to just plain If:

> If result ="y" or Session("customer_id") <> "" Then

...or you are placing your ElseIf after your previous one:

```
If result ="y" Then 
    Response.Write("The field is: " & result )
ElseIf result ="y" or Session("customer_id") <> "" Then  
    Do Something
End If
```

If it's the latter, then your ElseIf will not execute because the result = "y" condition has already been met in the previous If-statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your ElseIf statement does not appear to have a preceding If statement, unless you're leaving out some code somewhere.

You need:

```
If x Then
  Do something
ElseIf y Then
  Do something else
End If
```

You can't have ElseIf just sitting off on it's own.